# list pop and insert operation unexpected result

Tags: python

```
x=[1,2,3]

for i in range(1):
    for j in range(1):
        x.pop(0)
        print(x)
        x.insert(j,x[0])
        print(x)
```

This code output is unexpected [2, 2, 3] unlike the below code.

```
x=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(1):
        for j in range(1):
            c=x.pop(0)
            print(x)
            x.insert(j,c)
            print(x)
```

*both code 1 print x[0] as 2 but same pop value print correctly as 1 . why is that so*

**this is code 3**

```
x=[1,2,3]
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        #wanted to use 123 again and again but same address issue
        z=x
        c=z.pop(i)
        z.insert(j,x[i])
        #out of range issue

print(z)
```

I wanted to use this code for permutation of number.

Comment: But what do you want the code to do?

Comment: `z=x` creates another reference to `x`, not a new list which has the same elements.Thus `z.pop()` mutates `x`.  Perhaps you want `z=x[:]`, but your code is so obscure it is hard to know if that would fix it. Rolling your own permutation algorithm is a good learning experience, but if all you want are permutations of a list for some other purpose, use `itertools.permuatations()`

Comment: see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-cyclic-permutations-number/)

Comment: I thought code 1 will generated [1,2,3] so why there is  difference between code 1 and code 2 output.

Answer (score 0):

I explain what do your 3 codes

```
x=[1,2,3]
for i in range(1):
    for j in range(1):
        x.pop(0) # delete x[0], now x[0] is x[1] then 2
        print(x)
        x.insert(j,x[0]) # insert x[0] which was x[1] then 2
        print(x)

x=[1,2,3]
for i in range(1):
    for j in range(1):
        c=x.pop(0) # delete x[0] but save it in c before remove
        print(x)
        x.insert(j,c) # insert c, the backup of x[0] 
        print(x)

x=[1,2,3]
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        z=x
        c=z.pop(i)
        z.insert(j,x[i]) # when j or i == last iteration, it crash because you remove it with pop
```